# Create iterator from total difference

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I want to iterate through the integers from `x` up to `n` values further. I can do this for example with:

```
x.upto(x + n - 1)
```

or many other ways, but all of them require me to calculate the end myself, which seems not very elegant. Is there any way to create an iterator directly from the total difference to be iterated?

I imagine something like this:

```
5.up(10).to_a
# returns [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

I know I could easily write it myself, but I want to know if what I want already exists in the core.

Comment: `x.upto(x + n)` includes `x + n`, so shouldn't your example include `15`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
5.step.take(10) # => [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: You can also do `5.step(to:10).to_a #=> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` etc. Also worth mentioning for the OP that `steps` by default increments by 1, but this can be changed e.g., `5.step(by:2).take(3) #=> [5, 7, 9]` or `5.step(to:20,by:2).to_a #=> [5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]`.